# jersey servlet exception tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jersey

Am going nuts trying to start up a simple Jersey - Spring webapp. The error I get from Tomcat upon trying to access the web resources is:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Spring Web Application threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

root cause

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:69)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.create(ServletContainer.java:391)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.create(ServletContainer.java:306)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:607)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.28 logs.
```

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.companyname.abc</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and after some investigation and amak's tip that it had something to do with the hbase dependency it became clear that the problem was caused by HBase importing jersey 1.4 while i was using jersey 1.10 in my project. After excluding the jersey artifacts pulled in by HBase everything seems fine atm:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.90.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

hope that helps..

Comment: Similar problem occurred when using Swagger. Thanks!

Comment: @TomTasche +1 to you. I found this question while googling for "swagger with jersey and springservlet" and this turned out to be my issue, too.

Comment: +1 to you @TomTasche and fas this definitely saved some of my brain cells

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to get a basic example working, that shouldn't happen. Maybe you have a corrupt jersey-server jar. Try deleting your existing one and downloading a new one.

This error implies that your jar is missing the file `META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider`, which tells it which WebApplicationProvider to use.

Comment: strangley enough, I discovered it was the following entry to my pom file         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.90.3-cdh3u1 </version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Same for me. Removing the hbase 0.90.4 dependency fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case

`mvn dependency:tree`

showed my that another version of jersey-server was used. I was including version 1.12, but in the tree appeared

> com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9-ea07:compile

After fixing this weird dependency the error was gone.